# How can I add default command line parameters to an executable in a way that will also work on GUI apps?

Tags: shell, command-line, environment-variables, alias

I want to pass a command line program by default when I run it.

```
myprog --foo=bar
```

The solution I could think of was to add a custom "myprog" wrapper to my "bin" folder

```
#! /bin/sh
/usr/bin/myprog --foo=bar $@
```

The good thing is that since I set up my system so the bin folder is in the PATH both for interactive shells and for GUI apps, calling myprog from anywhere will pass the --foo flag by default, including if I run myprog from the applications menu.

However, I didn't like that I had to use the absolute path to `/usr/bin/myprog` in my wrapper script (if I don't it enters an infinite loop). Is there a better way to go at this?

Comment: Quote that `"$@"` otherwise it really won't do what you think it does. QUOTE YOUR VARIABLES !!!!!!!

Comment: @muru: Maybe there is a solution that doesn't require a wrapper script? The answers there seem a bit too complex for something that ought to be simple...

Comment: @roaima: what is the problem with not quoting the "$@" here? My intention is that separate arguments to `~/bin/myprog` should become separate arguments for `/usr/bin/myprog`

Comment: @hugomg pass one parameter that involves spaces and you'll find out. As for wrappers, that's why apps use configuration files and environment variables. If your app doesn't use either, you are out of luck.

Comment: @hugomg if you don't quote `$@` it's exactly the same as using `$*`, which re-splits words by whitespace even if they were initially quoted to protect them. See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/247127/what-is-and-in-linux) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448407/bash-script-to-receive-and-repass-quoted-parameters) for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alias` for that. From `man sh`:

Aliases
     An alias is a name and corresponding value set using the alias(1) builtin
     command.  Whenever a reserved word may occur (see above), and after
     checking for reserved words, the shell checks the word to see if it
     matches an alias.  If it does, it replaces it in the input stream with
     its value.  For example, if there is an alias called “lf” with the value
     “ls -F”, then the input:

```
       lf foobar ⟨return⟩

 would become

       ls -F foobar ⟨return⟩
```

Aliases provide a convenient way for naive users to create shorthands for
     commands without having to learn how to create functions with arguments.
     They can also be used to create lexically obscure code.  This use is dis‐
     couraged.

Comment: If I put an alias in my `.profile` will it also count when launching apps from the applications menu instead of from an interactive shell?